# P-values extremely low for linear mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, p-value

I am working with linear mixed effect models in Rstudio, using the package "nlme" and function "gls".

I have data for N=1800. For each participant, I have measured test score for 11 years, one per year. I want to check the association between metabolite X and the trajectory of tests (thus, I am using linear mixed effects models).

However, I am obtaining very low p-values (1.1E-150). This is probably because my database is very large, since I set the data in long format, and I have ~12,000 observations.

My question is: - If the p-values I get are wrong, how do I fix them?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think your p values are wrong?  How big is your effect? How small are your errors? Without a lot more detail, no one will be able to figure out if your p values are wrong, much less how to fix them.  It is VERY unlikely to be something about the nlme package. But you could have the wrong code, the wrong data, or who knows what.

Answer (score 2):

[If you have a large sample, even trivially small effects will be detected as significant.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bp-value%5D+large+sample) The p value calculation is almost certainly correct. It just very probably does not answer the question you are interested in.

p values and statistical significance quantify and address how likely it is to see data or test statistics as extreme as what you actually saw under the assumption that the null hypothesis is correct. This is only very tangentially related to questions of *clinical* significance, or "effects we care about".

You may want to look at effect sizes.